# react native string replace with image

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently working on a app where user can mention their friends.
If user inputs something with `@user1` I will get `user1`'s image and display on the message.

Lets say if user types `Hey @user1, whats up ?` then in place of `@user1`, his thumbnail should be displayed.

User's thumbnail is in its username path somewhere like `user1.jpg`

```
function getTextWithThumb(str) { 
        var withThumb =  str.replace(userCheckRegex, `<Image source=require("../" + ${$&} + ".jpg") />`) 
        return withThumb
}
```

Here I am stucked at returning `Image Component` along with text dynamically out of react component.

```
<Text>{getTextWithThumb("Hey @user1, whats up ?")}</Text>
```

Which should give something like,

```
<Text> Hey <Image source="some_source" />, whats up ? </Text>
```

Is there any way I can achieve this ? Really need help here.

Thank you

Comment: you're returning a string literal, you should be returning a whole component. You should prepare your string first, and then pass it to the require call on the source property and return the entire `<Image />` component, not a string literal wrapped in back ticks

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak that does not work either

Comment: Then the context you're doing this in is wrong. Where is `getTextWithThumb` is it a component method? If so what component is it on? Can you post the code?

Comment: No, its not component method. I want to replace a word in string with image returning a string that contains image

Comment: But strings can't contain images. See Colins answer, that is exactly what I described in my comment. You need to pass that Image component to some render function

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak it is supported. You can have image along side text. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/a0268a7bfc8000b5297d2b50f81e000d1f479c76 .

Comment: No thats not what I mean I mean that strings can't contain images. You're returning this from the function written above `"<Image source=... />"`. Which is why you should edit your function to match Colins example and then call it like he shows

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like:

```
function getTextWithThumb(str) { 
  const imageSource = str.replace(userCheckRegex, `require(../${$&}.jpg)`);
  return <Image source=`${imageSource}`/>  
}
```

Then later:

```
<Text>{`Hey, ${getTextWithThumb("@user1")}, what's up?`}</Text>
```

As @Robbie mentioned, you might have to have your `<Image />` within a `<View>` tag.

Comment: I have updated the question for what I am looking for. str.replace replaces the characters, words in string. I want a image in text.

Comment: I know, this function does that.

Comment: Deleted my answer since they are identical.  I'm not sure if `<Image />` is a valid child of `<Text>`

Comment: You could also try wrapping it all in a view tag 
`<Text>Hey,</Text>{getTextWithThumb("@user1")}<Text>what's up?</Text>` wrapped in a `<View />` with flex direction set to row but that will take a bit of styling to get it to look nice

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak it is valid child of Text